# Help proving that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=L$ and that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f'(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that if $f$ is a differentiable function on some $(c,\infty)$ and supposing that $\lim_{\rightarrow \infty} [f(x)+f'(x)]=L$, where L is finite, then  $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=L$ and that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f'(x)=0$. The hint the book gives is to set $f(x)=\frac{f(x)*e^x}{e^x}$, but I don't see how it could be useful.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using L'hospital's rule and the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)e^x) = (f(x) + f'(x))e^x$.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see it, I don't know why I was taking the derivative of the whole $f(x)$, when it was just of the numerator and denominator separately! Thanks!

Comment: @kobe Great to see you back!  +1 This is an oldie but a goodie.